# Eclipse -   c console displays unreadable characters in warning messages 

Tags: eclipse

Whenever I'm coding in C in Eclipse and I get an error after compiling my errors show up with unreadable characters in them...

Example

```
expected â€˜=â€™, â€˜,â€™, â€˜;â€™, â€˜asmâ€™ or â€˜__attribute__â€™ before â€˜validitycheckâ€™
```

I get the same thing when i roll over my mouse over errors...
I have tried to change my console encoding 
following the directions form 
http://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/

and trying every single encoding option 
to no avail

I had a problem with eclipse earlier it crushed because i had a `!` in my path directory
I moved eclipse to different path without a `!` and it worked fine. I wonder if this problem could also be caused by a `!` in a font path??

Comment: What is the internationalization of your OS?

Comment: It appears that the error message is being sent as UTF-8, but your terminal is displaying it in ISO 8859-15 or thereabouts.

Comment: Im not sure if thats the case the default option was Cp1252 but i tried changing it to UTF-8 as well as ISO 8859-15 and others but it did nothing for me

Answer (score 3):

This seems to have some info on the problem: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2006-08/msg00177.html. I don't know if you can fix it with Eclipse, however. Maybe if follow the solution, things will sort themselves out.

> This means that you have a discrepancy between your locale settings and
>   the terminal you are using.  For example, many distros set the locale
>   environment variables (LC_*) in the .bashrc type startup files to
>   something like en_US.UTF-8 by default.  This tells programs to use US
>   English messages (and sorting collations, etc.) with UTF-8 encoding. 
>   But if your terminal does not support the UTF-8 you will get garbage
>   characters when the program tries to use any code points outside of the
>   ascii range, in this case opening and closing quotes.
>
> The solution is to set your locale to match the capabilities of the
>   terminal that you are using.  If you can't figure this out you can
>   always use the default POSIX/C locale (e.g. "export LC_ALL=C") which
>   will only use standard ascii characters.
>
> This has nothing to do with the functionality of gcc or the code it
>   generates, only messages that it prints.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse IDE, go to Project-> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Tool Chain Editor and in Current toolchain, select the correct compiler. For me it was Cygwin GCC.